# DB2 SQL WHERE clause for Dynamic Column

Tags: sql, db2

I have created dynamic column in my statement. In my dynamic column, I have used various CASE statement. Now, I cannot filter my dynamic column in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
    item1, 
    item2, 
    CASE WHEN item1 = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3 FROM "Table1"
WHERE item3 = '10';
```

Above statement giving me error when I use filter on my dynamic column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to refer a table,

```
SELECT 
    item1, 
    item2, 
    CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3
FROM TABLE
```

Second, the `item3` is not an original column, because the `where` clause get executed before `select`, which means when `where` get executed, the `item3` does not exist.

```
You could do this way:

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    item1, 
    item2, 
    CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3,
FROM TABLE ) as A
WHERE A.item3 = '10'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `Where` clause is logically processed before `Select` so you cannot use the `Alias` name generated in `Select` in `Where` clause.

Also there is a unwanted *comma* after table name

you can use the `CASE` directly in `Where` clause

```
SELECT item1,
       item2,
       CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3
FROM   "Table1" --, unwanted comma
WHERE  CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END = '10'
```

I will probably go with other two answers if you have complex/nested `CASE` statement

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query up in a derived table:

```
select item1, item2, item3
from
(
    SELECT 
        item1, 
        item2, 
        CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3
    FROM tablename
) dt
WHERE item3 = '10';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//with cte
with tmp as (
SELECT 
item1, 
item2, 
CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3 
FROM "Table1"
)
select * from tmp where item3='10'

//with subselect
select * from (
SELECT 
item1, 
item2, 
CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3 
FROM "Table1"
) tmp where item3='10'

//with reuse case
SELECT 
    item1, 
    item2, 
    CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END AS item3
FROM tablename where CASE WHEN item = '1' THEN '10' END ='10'
```